# encrypt connection string using a custom encryption method

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config, connection-string

encrypting web.config connectionStrings section using .net standard approach , in a shared host is not possible .
I read in a blog that an alternative is to create a custom class or method to encrypt and decrypt web.config connectionStrings section .
 is this applicable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this article - based on crypt and decrypt

Link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5719/Simple-encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-C

Nota : You can use EnbededRessource in order to save your stringConnection if you don't want let users access

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify why it wouldn't be possible in a shared host? It "should" have it's own machine key (the encryption process must be done at the machine itself).

You can create a "disposable" aspx page (aka one time use) whose only purpose is to run the encryption method (once). You can then delete that page from your host. Assuming of course that the user instance running Asp.net has R/W access to your app folder(s) (to modify web.config).

Hth...

Comment: well , I've tried that but in shared hosts access is denied . I don't know why .